# How to link Gurobi solver in a CMake project (c++, Clion)?

Tags: cmake, clion, gurobi

I am using Gurobi solver in a C++ project. However, when I tried to build the project in Clion, I got the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

and many lines like:

```
  "__ZN6GRBEnv3setERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES7_", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
```

and

```
      __ZNSt3__16vectorIdNS_9allocatorIdEEE21__push_back_slow_pathIKdEEvRT_ in libgurobi_c++.a(LinExpr.o)
      __ZNSt3__16vectorI6GRBVarNS_9allocatorIS1_EEE21__push_back_slow_pathIKS1_EEvRT_ in libgurobi_c++.a(LinExpr.o)
```

the error information also contains:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [gurobitest] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gurobitest.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gurobitest.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [gurobitest] Error 2
```

Here is my CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(gurobitest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(GUROBI_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY "/library/gurobi912/mac64/include")
include_directories(${GUROBI_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY})
set(GUROBI_LIB_DIRECTORY "/library/gurobi912/mac64/lib")
link_directories(${GUROBI_LIB_DIRECTORY})

add_executable(gurobitest main.cpp ${GUROBI_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY}/gurobi_c++.h)

target_link_libraries(gurobitest gurobi_c++ gurobi91)
```

It seems I've already linked the library to the project properly, but it didn't work anyway. I really appreciate it for any help.

Comment: What compiler are you using and how was Gurobi built? It looks like you're using two different standard libraries